# Unable to change text-scaling-factor on gnome 3.30.2

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, scaling

On debian (testing) with gnome 3.30.2 I am unable to change the `text-scaling-factor` to 1.25. Neither the tweak-tool nor using the `gsettings` command works:
[image: Option grayed out]
As you can see on the screenshot the plus option is grayed out.

Using this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.25
```

I get this error:

```
The provided value is outside of the valid range
```

Using the command line I can set the scaling factor to something equal to or below 1, but every value greater than 1 gives me the above error.

I am absolutely certain I was able to do this a few days ago. I do not remember installing any updates since then. Several reboots and logouts did not fix the problem. I would like to avoid uninstalling/reinstalling software since this is a relatively new debian install and I doubt it would help.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux T470s 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-3 (2019-05-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Are there any logs I can look at to see what's wrong? How can I make that option available again?

I have tried turning the "Large Text" accessibility option on but that didn't help either.

The file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml` contains:

```
<key name="text-scaling-factor" type="d">
  <range min="0.5" max="3.0"/>
  <default>1.0</default>
  <summary>Text scaling factor</summary>
  <description>
    Factor used to enlarge or reduce text display, without changing font size.
  </description>
</key>
<key name="scaling-factor" type="u">
  <default>1</default>
  <summary>Window scaling factor</summary>
  <description>
    Integer factor used to scale windows by. For use on high-dpi screens.
    0 means pick automatically based on monitor.
  </description>
</key>
```

Comment: Can you set in *Tweaks > Fonts > Scaling Factor* the value to 1.25 and restart?

Comment: @harrymc As you can see on the screenshot the plus option is grayed out, also if I enter the number directly it resets to 1.00 when I hit enter.

Comment: What do you have in the XML file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml` for the tag `text-scaling-factor` (add the tag to the post)? Do you have a line saying `<range min="0.5" max="3.0"/>`?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to include the content of that XML file

Comment: The contents seem correct. Change the `<default>` tag to `1.25`, save the file, in su mode run the command `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, then reboot.

Comment: Already tried that, tried it again now and it still doesn't work

Comment: Does the above make *Tweaks > Fonts > Scaling Factor* to become modifiable?

Comment: No, it unfortunately does not

Comment: I can't make this happen at my end, so here is a last try: In *Settings > Universal Access*, is "Large text" enabled?

Comment: I thought it might have been something to do with the accessibility options after looking at the code but I already tried that and it didn't work. I guess it's gonna be a fresh install then, at least it's an opportunity to test my Ansible skills again.

Comment: I thought it would come to this, as everything seems correct but nothing is working.

Comment: Could it be some issue with the messaging bus, dbus missing or something? Have you tried complaining to the GNOME people? https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/IRC

Comment: I don't think going to them would particularly help because in my case it was probably an edge case and I can't reproduce it anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that even though all the configs were right, the only solution was to reinstall Debian. It now works like intended. I suspect a gnome extension to remove the accessibility menu had something to do with it.